# How to use the "native" GUI look with Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

By default Tkinter still uses the old Windows 2000-style widgets (random example):

[image: windows 2000 run dialog]

but I want it to use the Windows XP/Vista/7-style widgets instead:

[image: windows xp run dialog]

How can I do this? I would prefer to use the latest style version, so Windows 7 > Vista > XP > 2000.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On Windows, use [tkinter.ttk](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html) to get the the themed version of Tk.

Comment: But Tkinter is a platform-independent library, so if an answer doesn't say anything about platform it can be reasonably assumed that the answer applies for all platforms. I'll remove my comments.

Answer (score 3):

The ttk themed widgets are what you are looking for. Be sure to use the 'vista' theme to get native appearance on Vista/Win7.