# Change bg color of tkSimpleDialog

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to change bg color of [tkSimpleDialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) to match my system default bg color:

GTK:

[image: GTK]

tk:

[image: tk]

I tried to put `config(bg='#CCC9C1')` everywhere I can think of, but I managed to make only for some parts from dialog.

Is it possible to change bg color in tkSimpleDialog?

---

Code sample:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog

class MyDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):

        Label(master, text="First:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Second:").grid(row=1)

        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)

        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = int(self.e1.get())
        second = int(self.e2.get())
        print first, second # or something

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

d = MyDialog(root)
```

Comment: Have you tried editing tkSimpleDialog.py, as shown in the link you provided? I would try `bg='#CCC9C1'` for the Frame itself (the `body` object in this case).

Comment: yes, I tried that by entering `self.config(...)` in body function, but no good. Here is screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/M4YHY.png I thought there must be some more global way. I added the same to the `root = Tk()` but it only colors the root window (which I .withdraw, of course)

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the module itself. I just tried that and it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Well, `body.config(bg='#CCC9C1')` in `tkSimpleDialog.py` has effect, but partial - it colors body frame bg, which is where text label and input box are placed, but bg of text label is still light gray, as well as other elements like buttons. Now I could set this bg color to every item separatelly, but it doesn't feel good, as any other script will have "patchworked" dialogs. So I'm wondering where is default bg color defined for Tk? That way I can set it for good

Comment: Did some searching and edited my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

Found way out. As mentioned `root.config(...)` changes appearance just on root window (side window that we always usually hide). For global settings we are encouraged to use Tk database file (i.e. named `optionDB`) which has same format as `.Xdefaults` (X resource database) file. Then we use it in a script like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.option_readfile('optionDB')
```

Even better, for some reason discouraged, we can set 'global' settings in a script directly:

```
root = Tk()
root.option_add('*background', '#CCC9C1')
root.option_add('*Entry*background', '#FFFFFF')
```

Available keywords are:

> *font
>   *Label*font
>   *background
>   *Entry*background
>   *foreground
>   *Listbox*foreground

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may just need to use the [tkinter.ttk library](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.ttk.html), which is the themed version of Tk as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7385518/404469). Hope it helps.

Here's the reference for Python 2.x, currently 2.7: http://docs.python.org/library/ttk.html

Comment: That's good to know. It seems like it is available only in Python 3

Comment: @zetah: ttk is also available in python 2.7, and as a separately installable module for 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: @Bryan: True, I'm playing with it now... Looks better than bare tkinter, (i.e. 'clam' theme) but I misunderstood that it provides native controls, which is not the case here